# How do you compute for fc and t in modulating an I and Q component

Tags: sampling, digital-communications, quadrature

I know that in a $2^b$-ary QAM system you need to modulate the $I$ and $Q$ components through the mixer and are separated by 90° through a local oscillator (by applying a $\cos$ and $\sin$).

By mixing them through the mixer, the $I$ component will be multiplied by a $\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ and $Q$ by $\sin(2\pi f_c t)$. My question is, if I have a 8 bit sampler and the sampling frequency I used is 10 kHz, what will be my value for the carrier frequency $f_c$ and the time sweep, $t$?

My idea is that I can compute the carrier frequency by computing for the symbol rate (bit rate over the number of symbols) and multiplying it by 2 to satisfy the Nyquist Sampling rate. Is that true? And I really don't have any idea what increment value of $t$ I will use.

Comment: Do you mean "$2^b$-ary AFSK" when you say "2^b-AM"?

Comment: 2^b - ary QAM sorry. Basically what I used is 16 QAM

Comment: You seem to be confused about what is what in your formulas. You don't "use" a value of $t$. $t$ stands for the ongoing time – it's your independent variable, if you will so!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it depends on the pulse shape.

A 16-QAM baseband signal can be written as $$s_{BB}=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_k p(t-kT_p),$$ where $a_k$ is a complex symbol taken from your 16-QAM constellation, $R_p=1/T_p$ is the pulse rate (how many pulses per second you transmit), and $p(t)$ is the pulse shape (ideally, $p(t)$ is a Nyquist pulse).

The bandwidth of $s_{BB}(t)$ is the same as the bandwidth of $p(t)$ (assuming you're transmitting uncorrelated data). Assume this bandwidth is $B$. Then, after mixing with the carrier, the passband signal's maximum frequency is $f_c+B$, and you need a sampling frequency $f_s>2(f_c+B)$ to satisfy Nyquist.

If you don't know what the pulse shape is, then you're probably transmitting rectangular, non-overlapping pulses. As a rule of thumb, I define the bandwidth of a rectangular pulse as five times the pulse rate: $B=5R_p$. Note that many textbook authors, such as Stallings, use $B=R_p$. I prefer to be conservative and define a larger bandwidth.

Then, your sampling frequency is $f_s>2(f_c+5R_p)$.

As an example, let's say that you want to transmit 1000 pulses per second, with a carrier frequency of 1 MHz, and rectangular pulses. Then,

```
fs = 2*(1e6+5*1000);  % or larger
t = 0:1/fs:Tend       % Tend depends on how many pulses you transmit
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. So I am true regarding my statement above, that my carrier frequency is 2 times the symbol rate to satisfy Nyquist? And my t depends on the pulseshape, which means 1/symbol rate?

Comment: Not the carrier frequency -- the _sampling_ frequency. You can choose your carrier frequency to be anything, as long as it's larger than $B$. Please see the example I added to my question.

Comment: On the other hand, if your sampling frequency is given and cannot be changed, then that will certainly impose a limit on your max carrier frequency, which would be $f_s/2-5R_p$.

Comment: @LeBlancLord Is there something still unclear or that hasn't been satisfactorily answered by Dan or me?

Comment: So if everything is clear, why didn't you up vote or accept an answer?

Comment: @LeBlancLord Please consider upvoting/accepting those answers that were useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an analog upconversion of the baseband signal, either to an analog IF signal for further conditioning or direct to your RF carrier (referred to as direct conversion or Zero-IF). Note that you could also use a digital IF frequency with a single real data stream representing your modulated waveform, and you would perform the above functions digitally and then use a single DAC and analog mixer. In this case, to optimize analog filtering later, a best choice for the digital IF frequency in that case would be $f_s/4$ as this will sample the signal within the Nyquist boundary.

Sticking with your approach as presented, your carrier is at DC since you are providing I and Q components to a quadrature mixer.   You could provide a digital IF with I and Q output and then structure your upconversion as a single-sided upconverter as well, and in this approach you would consider the benefit of cancellation of one of the sidebands from the upconverter, typically 25 to 30 dB without more sophisticated cancellation due to analog limitations. This is quite limited in the analog world however- For example, if you had a digital IF at 2.5 KHz and provided upconversion in the analog using a 100 MHz Local Oscillator, you would have one spectrum at 100 MHz + 2.5 KHz and another at 100 MHz - 2.5 KHz, and it would be nearly impossible to filter out the desired of the two (given the very high ratio of carrier to Digital IF, but using your 10KHz sampling)...but a single sided upconverter using a digital I and Q output to your quadrature mixer would allow for 25 to 30 dB of suppression (still not enough in most applications).

If you do any form of pulse shaping (which you should if you care about spectral efficiency), you will need at least two samples per symbol when you create your baseband signal (using I and Q). Typically the unit samples (complex impulses) representing your I Q symbols are zero stuffed to upsample followed by the pulse shaping filter) resulting in your I Q data stream for upconversion.  You will then want to review your analog solution to make the trade between higher digital sampling rates or tighter analog filtering.